# Shell - Fix 80 column wrap limit

Tags: centos, shell, stty

I have several Centos servers that enforce an 80 column limit when I ssh into them, rather than being dynamic and going to the width of whatever shell I am using as seen here:
[image]

.

Is there a way to update the settings (perhaps an stty command) in order to have the column width update to the width of whatever shell I am using (gnome-shell with ubuntu). I notice that if I perform stty -a on my ubuntu terminal the column number keeps updating to whatever width I am set to, but the centos server I ssh into does not.

For some reason I do not have this same problem when I ssh into ubuntu servers and seems to be centOS specific.

Comment: This is not something CentOS does by default. Someone specifically customized your system to behave this way. Contact that person.

Comment: No. I have set up/installed these servers myself. Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that they are Supermicro servers with ipmi access?

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?

Comment: I was just plucking at straws as I have not manually configured CentOS to behave differently, and this happens to my supermicro servers and not my desktops that I install centos to.

Comment: Are you trying to ssh to the IPMI console?

Comment: nono, this is just a normal ssh session. If CentOS does not do this by default I will have to search for other reasons.

Comment: I ever had similar problems on one system. Try `kill -s SIGWINCH $$` or add it in your shell rc files. Not sure if this would help for your case.

Comment: That didn't help. Could this be a cpanel default setting/option?

Comment: What does it say when you run 'echo $TERM'?  Do that both on the local system before sshing into the CentOS system and again when you're on the CentOS system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue a few months ago with a non-CentOS server. That was resolved by fixing an issue I had in my TCL expect script that I use to log into the servers with. The fix can be found on this other Stack Overflow post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45454452/expect-script-fixing-weird-terminal-resizing-behaviour

I'm pretty sure this was the issue I was having 10 years ago now.

Hopefully this post will help others redirect to the actual real issue.

Answer (score 0):

yes, that's pretty standard CentOS behavior.  if you can figure out the size of the xterm where you're running ssh then set them manually (stty columns 196 rows 142) and then clear the screen it seems to work.  that's not very optimal though.  its just another user interface fail.

Comment: I am at a 100% CentOS shop and never seen this as standard behavior.

Comment: Same as @yoonix , this isn't standard for CentOS